# .net 5 MVC multiselectlist not returning values in a multi-part form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multi-select

We have a form with multiple patients and multiple different fields.  We have a section for flags of which multiple can be selected.  This is the form result:

[image: Form view]

We can get the other fields to submit.  However, the flag field will not send values.  I have tried several different things and I can't get any values in the model that are posted for flag.

Here is our patients model:

```
public class Patients
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public int CA_ALERTId { get; set; }
    public int? NON_ALERTId { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public List<Notes> Notes { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string OffSiteLocation { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PatientFlags> PatientFlags { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public MultiSelectList FlagsMulti { get; set; }
}
```

In the view we have this for the for the flag part of the form:

```
<td>
      <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Patients.PatientFlags" />
                            
      @Html.ListBox("Id", (MultiSelectList)@Patients.FlagsMulti)
</td>
```

It seems to render correctly presenting the options.  It also seems to output the correct HTML:
[image: form html]

In the controller:

```
 public async Task<JsonResult> Edit(Patients patients)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("***Editing Patiient");
        if(patients.Note != null)
        {
            await CreateNote(patients);
        }
        Patients patient = _context.Patients.Find(patients.Id);
        if(patients.State != null)
        {
            patient.State = patients.State;
        }
        if (patients.Location != null)
        {
            patient.Location = patients.Location;
        }
        if (patients.OffSiteLocation != null)
        {
            patient.OffSiteLocation = patients.OffSiteLocation;
        }
        patient.FlagsMulti = patients.FlagsMulti;
        if(patients.PatientFlags != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("*********Adding Patient Flags"+patients.PatientFlags);
            foreach(PatientFlags pf in patients.PatientFlags)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("*******/adding patient flag"+pf.FlagId);
                patient.PatientFlags.Add(pf);
            }
            
        }
        _context.Update(patient);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); ....
```

The data coming back does not include anything for flagsmulti or patientflags.

I see plenty of examples online for getting results from a multi-select box by itself, they say you have to receive an int array.  However, I can't find a good example of when the multi-select has to be a part of a model. Any help on how I can access this data from the multi select along with the other model data would be much appreciated.

-- Edit after @Conman_123 suggestion
I changed the helper to:

```
<select asp-for="@Patients.PatientFlags" asp-items="@Patients.FlagsMulti"></select>
```

and the HTML output is now this --
[image: html after edit]

However, I still don't get anything sent back in the model.  patientflags is still empty --
[image]

Comment: From the generated HTML it looks like your ViewModel has the "Patients" object as a nested property, while the "patients" parameter for your `Edit` action is not nested? Does the `name` attribute for the inputs that are working also look like `Patients.Location`? Or are they just like `Location`?

Comment: @Conman_123 the HTML for others looks like this -- <input class="notes ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" id="Patients_Note" name="Patients.Note" value="" autocomplete="off"> and yes they work fine.  Also yes Patients is a list in the view model. I am only updating patients in this view but the view has some other data from other models that is in the view model.

Comment: Could you try manually set the `name` to "PatientFlags" (without the nesting) and see if that works? Usually you only use the "nested" property naming if it is actually in a nested property on your model.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<select>` has the `name` attribute set to 'Id', so it will try to bind to a model property called 'Id'.

Remove that hidden input with the `name` 'Patients.PatientFlags' and change your multiselect to have that `name` so it will bind correctly to your model.

You can do this using the [select tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-select-tag-helper). For example:

```
<select asp-for="Country" asp-items="Model.Countries"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, that didn't seem to resolve the issue.  I still get back a count of 0, see edits above.  Thanks again.